# Cannot do 1st login after installation of 20.04.01

Tags: login, login-screen

I'm sure of the password because I've used it to install some updates right after installing Ubuntu 20.04.01 It's the first time I login after installation.

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and it just says wrong login.

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Welcome! When does it say 'wrong login'? Is it after you enter the password?

Comment: I found the answer or rather my mistake by self. Thank you anyway, Tanvir!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've realized that I had configured Ubuntu with an US Keyboard layout(QWERTY) instead of a Belgian keyboard layout(AZERTY).
The solution was to type the correspondent keys of the US keyboard on the Belgian keyboard - layouts easily found on the web.